# Using datetime.replace() in a datetime subclass

Tags: python, datetime, subclass

I want to subclass `datetime.datetime` and add a property `ticks` to get / set the sub-second part as fractions of 65536 (0x10000) instead of microseconds. (This is to mimic the IEC 61375-1 TIMEDATE48 data type, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59400679).)

My attempt so far:

```
import datetime

class MyDateTime(datetime.datetime):

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
         return super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

    @property
    def ticks(self):
         return int(self.microsecond / 1000000 * 0x10000)

    @ticks.setter
    def ticks(self, ticks_):
        # self.microsecond = int(ticks_ / 0x10000 * 1000000)                # attribute 'microsecond' is not writeable
        self.replace(microsecond=int(ticks_ / 0x10000 * 1000000))           # replace() returns a new datetime object
        # self = self.replace(microsecond=int(ticks_ / 0x10000 * 1000000))  # doesn't work either
```

As I cannot assign the `microsecond` attribute directly, I am using `replace()` as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183707). But this returns a new `datetime.datetime` object instead of manipulating `self`. Pointing `self` to this new object doesn't work either.

**What's the right way to overwrite `datetime.datetime.microsecond` in the `ticks` property of my subclass?**

I also stumbled upon [this pitfall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42523288) when passing a timezone in the constructor of a datetime subclass. Is it *at all* possible or recommended to subclass `datetime.datetime` in a universal way?

Comment: Subclassing built-ins is often problematic if not impossible. Suggest you just define your own "datetime-like" class. Typing in Python isn't strict so if it's enough like a `datetime` you can probably get away with doing that. Look up "duck typing".

Comment: @stovfl If I do as you suggest, and then `dt = MyDateTime(2019, 12, 20, microsecond=123456); dt.ticks=(0x10000/2)` then
`dt.microsecond` is still 123456 and not 500000 (0.5s) as expected. And for me `isinstance(t, datetime.datetime)` is `True`. _Python 3.7.1_

Comment: @rikinet: Checked myself, the property `dt.microsecond` returns `self._microsecond` but this attribute does not exist in object `datetime`. Therefore `self._microsecond =` create  a new attribute which is not used from the property.